# API throws exception of System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, exception, casting

I am trying to send data to my ag-grid, but it throws exception of:-

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

The float field here is showing the cast invalid:-

```
var listData = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new opGrid()
{
   ID = s.Field<int>("ID"),
   Quantity = s.Field<int?>("Quantity"),
   Mass = s.Field<float?>("Mass"),
});
```

The class used is:-

```
public class opGrid
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int? Quantity { get; set; }
   public float? Mass { get; set; }
}
```

The SQL Server database also has **Mass** as *float* with multiple Null values.

Comment: T-SQL's `FLOAT` being a double-precision floating-point type (so `double` in C#) is a common source of confusion. For completeness, the single-precision floating-point type (`float` in C#) is `REAL`.

Answer (score 1):

A sql `Float` is a `Double` in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#Mtps_DropDownFilterText

so use:

```
Mass = s.Field<double?>("Mass"),
```

If you need a `float?`, simply cast it:

```
Mass = (float?) s.Field<double?>("Mass"),
```

Comment: Whoa there, "simply cast[ing]" floating-point values is rarely what you want, what with the loss of precision. If a `float?` is really needed here, it's more likely the DB type needs to change to `REAL`. Note that even the inverse (going from single to double precision) can lead to surprises, since the closest single-precision approximation of a number and the closest double-precision approximation are different.